# Changing color of back arrow button in left side of searchview in android

Tags: java, android, toolbar, searchview

My Codes:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarThreeLineColor"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

  <style name="ToolbarThreeLineColor" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorWhite</item>      <!-- 3 çizgi alt alta -->
</style>
<style name="ToolbarThreeLineColorBlack" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorBlack</item>      <!-- 3 çizgi alt alta -->
</style>


  if (isColorDark(color)){
        tool.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_border);
        tool.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tool.getContext().setTheme(R.style.ToolbarThreeLineColor);

    }else{
        tool.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_border_color_black_24dp);
        tool.setTitleTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tool.getContext().setTheme(R.style.ToolbarThreeLineColorBlack);

    }
```

I have a toolbar and search action is provided on this toolbar.

[my toolbar.](https://i.hizliresim.com/GZV5dV.jpg)

I want to change the color of the arrow to black. How can I do this?

[arrow.](https://i.hizliresim.com/RgMBda.jpg)

Comment: Your question is not clear, so please ask clear question and also add code snippet for that as well

Comment: How do I change the color of the arrow used to exit the search?